# SSMS - Restore database failed because .mdf cannot be overwritten

Tags: sql-server, ssms, database-restore

I am trying to restore a DB from the backup. Suddenly, it is giving me the following error everytime while trying to restore.

> Restore of database 'Something_Secret' failed.
> The file 'C:\Some\Path\Something_Secret.mdf' cannot be overwritten. It is being used by database 'Something_Secreter'.

How to get rid this of error?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use the UI for this, since this won't be the last thing it gets wrong for you. Learn the [`RESTORE DATABASE` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql).

```
RESTORE DATABASE Something_Secret_NewName
  FROM DISK = 'D:\Baseline\Path\To\Something_Secret.bak'
  WITH REPLACE, RECOVERY, 
  MOVE 'Something_Something_Logical_Primary'
    TO 'C:\Program Files\...\Something_Secret_NewName.mdf',
  MOVE 'Something_Something_Logical_Log'
    TO 'C:\Program Files\...\Something_Secret_NewName.ldf';
```

If you want more specific guidance, show the output of:

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = 'D:\Baseline\Path\To\Something_Secret.bak';
```

Comment: Can't agree with this more.  That UI needs to go....

Comment: Earlier I could do this using UI. Did something change?

Comment: Yeah you could do it before the database existed in that location, but you can only do that once.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for those who would like to continue using the UI (I'm using version 15.+). Once you select the backup media, click the "Files" link in the menu on the left. This will display a dialog that allows you to change the names of the db's files. In the "Restore As" field change the name of the files to match the name of your database.
[image]

Alternatively, you could add a level to the directory after the "DATA" directory where the new directory is the name of your database and leave the actual files names as they are.